# Eigen-values of $A$ and $B = A -kI$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$, $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices and $B = A -kI$, where $k$ is a real number and $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Then can we say that $A$ and $B$ have same eigenvectors?

My attempt: take $x$ which is eigenvalue of $A$ then $Au = xu$, and $(A- kI)u = Au -ku = (x-k)u = Bu$. So if $x$ is eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $u$ then $x-k$ is eigenvalue of $B$ with corresponding  eigenvector $u$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: what i tried is that: take  x which is eigenvalue of A then  Au = xu ,  and (A- k*I)*u = Au -ku = (x-k)u = Bu (by definition of B)  so if x is eigenvalue of A  corresponding vector u then x-k is eigenvalue of B corresponding vector u.

Comment: and approached similarly from opposite side , concluded that A and B have same eigenvectors

Comment: You talk about eigenvalues. How do you obtain the "same eigenvectors"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde i edited my first  comment check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can say that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors. The justification that you provided is correct.